# What happens here: sum += i++;?

Tags: java, logic, increment, postfix-operator

I have this simple piece of code but I don't understand this part: `sum += i++` .

```
int num1 = 5;
int sum = 0;
         
if (num1 < 100) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
        sum += i++; //?
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
} else {
    sum = -1;
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

The result I get is 6 and I don't understand how and why.

Comment: This looks like a great candidate for using a debugger, to step through each line of code one-by-one and to see how each variable's value changes, step-by-step. You can even follow along with the walk-throughs provided by the answers here, as you do so.

Comment: @andrewjames While this might give you some insight to the changing values, it won't explain *why* the values change the way they do.

Comment: Yes - I agree, @TiMauzi. The syntax explanations in the answers help a lot with that.

Answer (score 13):

`sum += i++` is equivalent to `sum = sum + i; i = i + 1`

---

This translates your code to:

```
int num1 = 5;
int sum = 0;
         
if (num1 < 100) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) //<-- i is incremented
        sum = sum + i; //<-- sum gets incremented by i here
        i = i + 1; //<-- i is incremented again, increment/loop-cycle ratio = 2
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
} else {
    sum = -1;
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

`i` is incremented by 2 each loop cycle and `sum` is incremented by `i` every loop cycle.

---

The result is 6  because:

You start the loop where `i` is 0 and `sum` is 0.

On the first loop cycle `sum` is incremented by 0, `i` is incremented by 2 (2).

On the second loop cycle, `sum` is incremented by 2 (2) and `i` is incremented by 2 (4).

On the third loop cycle, `sum` is incremented by 4 (6) and `i` is incremented by 2 (6).

At this point, `i` no longer satisfies the condition `i < num1` where `num1` is 5, and ends the loop.

Comment: why do i get a 6 then?

Comment: I would add that the position of the ++ matters. For example if you had ++i it would mean that i is increased by 1 before it's read, while i++ means that the value of i is read before it's increased by 1

Comment: Clear explanation! @HaibraynGonzález, the postfix increment operation is clear from the opening line of the answer itself.

Answer (score 3):

In every round, the variable `i` is getting incremented before a new loop round (`i++` in the loop header) **and** *after* the line `sum += i++;`.

This leads to `i` being `0, 2, 4` consecutively for each time, the line mentioned is called. After `i=4` and `i` being incremented by the loop, the loop stops. Thus, `sum=0+2+4=6` is your output.

This behavior is to be expected because of the postfix incrementation, with the operators in `i++` following *after* the variable. This implies `i` being incremented *after* the definition of `sum`. If you analoguously try the prefix notation `++i`, you should get a different result.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is executed 3 times, first i=0, then sum is not incremented since i++ is post-increment, note that i is incremented twice at each iteration.

Second iteration i = 2, third iteration i = 4

sum = 0 +2 +4 = 6

Answer (score 1):

Use paper to write a table as below, use a debugger and/or add some more printing to code.

```
| num1 | sum |  i  | i++ | values before statement is executed, result on next line 
|      |     |     |     | num1 = 5
|   5  |     |     |     | sum = 0
|   5  |  0  |     |     | if (num1 < 100)  // true, exxecute if block
|   5  |  0  |     |     | for (int i = 0;
|   5  |  0  |  0  |     | for (.........; i < num1;  // true, iterate
|   5  |  0  |  0  |     |    ...... i++ // i is increment, old value summed
|   5  |  0  |  1  |  0  |    sum += " (0)
|   5  |  0  |  1  |     | for (.........; ........; i++)
|   5  |  0  |  2  |  1  | for (.........; i < num1;  // true, iterate
|   5  |  0  |  2  |     |   ...... i++ // i is increment, old value summed|
|   5  |  0  |  3  |  2  |   sum += " (2)
|   5  |  2  |  3  |     | // and so on
.
.
.
```

(debugger may be a bit more complicated to start, but it is a good way to understand what a program is doing and almost essential for debugging code)